# Unable to create a bean for a service class present inside a jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have a Spring Boot project where I have an external dependency jar. In that jar there is an interface as below :

```
public interface Feature {

  List<FeatureResponse> getFeatures(FeatureRequest req);

}
```

Its implementation is:

```
@Service
public class FeatureImpl implements Feature {

    public List<FeatureResponse> getFeatures(FeatureRequest featureReq) {
        // do something
        return featureList;
    }
}
```

Now in my Spring Boot project inside one my class I have used the request and response to object the feature list. However, though it compiles, it fails to run. The error is simple bean creation error at the injection point of Autowired that we get. Below is my class:

```
@Component
public class FeatureServiceImpl implements featureService { 

    @Autowired
    Feature feature;

    -----

}
```

The injection with @Autowired is not happening here.

Comment: What you show so far looks OK.  If you're getting a bean creation error, then there must be more to this than what you're showing, as the problem would be specific to how Spring is attempting to instantiate that object.  Please provide the full error message you're getting, including the complete stack trace. Put it in your question.

Comment: It would also be useful to know which packages `Feature`, `FeatureImpl`, `FeatureServiceImpl` and your class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` are in.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration class or your SpringBootApplication class add the following

```
@ComponentScan({"base.package.of.your.currentJar","base.package.of.your.ImportedJar"})
```

Comment: Rather than adding `@ComponentScan` to a class already annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, you should use the `scanBasePackages` or `scanBasePackageClasses` attributes of `@SpringBootApplication`.